# API's calls via wso2 API Manager are not working with Chrome Browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, api, wso2

we have different API's written in node.js and it has a wso2 API Manager layer above it.
We are calling these APIs (token, Login, User, Survery etc) using Postman, Android App and it is working.
We have an Admin Panel webapp developedwith html,css,angular.js which calls same APIs (token,login etc)is again working on Internet explorer but get blocked on Chrome and Firefox.

OPTIONS https://10.51.227.185:8243/tanishka/1.0.0/user/login (anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:93p @ angular.min.js:89g @ angular.min.js:86(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:119n.$eval @ angular.min.js:133n.$digest @ angular.min.js:130n.$apply @ angular.min.js:133h @ angular.min.js:87K @ angular.min.js:91z.onload @ angular.min.js:93
(index):1

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://10.51.227.185:8243/tanishka/1.0.0/user/login. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401

[image]

Comment: I guess u need Authorization Bearer header in request

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the access token in `Authorization Bearer` HTTP header with the API invocation.